# Raphael.js - registering multiple events to element

Tags: javascript, events, raphael

my problem is that I need handle multiple events for rectangle. That sound simple,
for example this works

```
  node.click(function(e){
     click(); // this is function defined in same scope, it works ok
  });

  node.mouseout(function(e){
     mouseout();  
  });
```

But, I want to automatize this, so it should looks like this:

```
var events = new Array("click", "mouseout");
for(var i in events){
     node[events[i]](function(e){
         events[i](); /*THIS is problem, no matter if it is click or mouseout
                        this always fires function with same name as last item
                        in events array (in this case mouseout) 
                      */
     }
}
```

Do you have any idea why a how I should solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handlers created in a loop are sharing a variable. By the time they are called, the variable is the last value in the loop.

You have to use a technique I call "freezing your closures" so that each handler gets a separate copy of the shared variable. In your case, the shared variable that changes is `i`

Your other problem is that you want to call your functions "click/mouseout" from a string, so you have to get a handle to the function, right now your code is attempting to call `"hello"()` which does not work

Your last problems (but not a bug yet) are that you shouldn't use the Array constructor and you shouldn't use a `for in` loop to iterate over arrays.

```
function createHandler(eventName) {
    return function(e) {
        window[eventName]();
    }
}

var events = ["click", "mouseout"];
for(var i=0; i < events.length; i++){
     node[events[i]](createHandler(events[i]));
}
```

The above example is easier to comprehend but you could use self invoking anonymous functions to do the same thing

```
var events = ["click", "mouseout"];
for(var i=0; i < events.length; i++){
     node[events[i]]((function(eventName){
         return function(e) {
             window[eventName]();
         };
     })(events[i]));
}
```

Comment: @user1905088 I'm working on it, just wanted to get the explanation there

Comment: Nice, I prefer the second solution.. BUT.. now I have
node[events[i]] = function(e){
                alert("ok");
                alert(e);
            }(events[i]);  

It fires ok, click, ok, mouseout when it is stared, but it don't fires when I click or mouseout the rectangle.. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1905088 I have no clue what you mean... `node[events[i]] = function(e){ alert("ok"); alert(e); }` is not what I suggested you use. Create a http://jsfiddle.net to show your problem

Comment: I missed the part with return, but it has no  effect http://jsfiddle.net/hDnkg/4/

Comment: You have to pass the handler into the click() and mouseout() functions, But something is still weird... http://jsfiddle.net/hDnkg/7/

Comment: And the problem seems to be with Rafael, a simple example like http://jsfiddle.net/hDnkg/8/ doesn't seem to get the click correct

Comment: So because there was no fill, the hotspot of the element was just the border? That kind of makes sense?